# C# book about intersection 3D surface and 2D plane

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d

Could you advise me for a C# graphics programming book about intersection 3D surface and 2D plane.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is more about the maths than the language. My suggestion would be that you rather try to get the best book on the topic even if the samples are in some other language. IMHO, having material that is well explained and sufficiently comprehensive outweighs the language specifics.

Comment: good advice.  i'd even recommend two books: one on general C# graphics programming, one on the math.